# Is $[0, 1]$, with the discrete topology, compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Is $[0, 1]$, with the discrete topology, compact?

This was on my exam today and I have no idea how to approach it. I thought of using $\mathcal{A}=\{[x, x+0.1]\}$ as an open cover of $[0, 1]$ but it didn't work.

Comment: What theorems do you know about compact spaces?

Comment: did you study for the exam, do you know the definition of the discrete topology? You already got three answers (which I would guess were posted more or less simultaneously right after you posted the question), do you follow them? If so, perhaps you should accept an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No infinite set $X$ endowed with the discrete topology is compact, because $\bigl\{\{x\}\,|\,x\in X\bigr\}$ is an open cover with no finite subcover.

Answer (score 2):

Every infinite set $X$ with the discrete topology isn't compact. This is a consequence of the fact that
$$
\bigcup_{x \in X}\{x\}
$$
is an open cover of $X$ which has no finite subcover.

Comment: Formally, $\bigcup_{x \in X}\{x\}$ is not a cover. $\bigcup_{x \in X}\{x\}=X$, and $X$ is not a cover. A cover is a family of sets, the union of those sets equals $X$. So, $\{\{x\}:x \in X\}$ is an open cover (which is what you mean), and $\{X\}$ is another open cover, but $\bigcup_{x \in X}\{x\}=\bigcup\{\{x\}:x \in X\}=X$ is not an open cover.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I noticed it after I submitted the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In the discrete topology every set is open. That includes the singleton sets. $[0, 1]$ is covered by the set of all singleton sets. Can it be covered by a finite set of singleton sets?